# Firebase-InApp-Message show only one time in Smartphone

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

After implementing firebase dependencies to show firebase-in-app-massage. It works properly but one time. Then, If I again send message its not working..

Comment: could you provide some code so we might be able to find out why it's not working?

Comment: Nope, I only put dependencies of Firebase-in-app-massage.           implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:18.0.2'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the firebase in-app messaging document, it retrieves messages from the server once per day (on both iOS and Android)

> To conserve power, Firebase In-App Messaging only retrieves messages from the server once per day. That can make testing difficult, so the Firebase console allows you to specify a test device that displays messages on demand.

Link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/get-started?authuser=0&platform=android#send_a_test_message

Answer (score 1):

Firebase In-App Messaging will show each message at most once per day on a device, to prevent spamming the user. Jason covered that topic in this [#AskFirebase episode](https://youtu.be/lG0FzoiFHDk?t=122).

It also by default only retrieves messages from the server once per day. Since this makes testing hard, you can mark you device as a test device as shown in the documentation on [sending test messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/get-started#send_a_test_message).

Comment: It means, I have not to worried... Its working fine ????    And also i have not to write some extra code

Comment: hello frank ...my inapp message only works test message (like it shows only when put instance id and test) but when i publish that campaign it shows running whenn it will published??